# How do I resize ONLY the background on a Custom ProgressBar (Android)?

Tags: android, progress-bar, android-progressbar

I have a custom style for ProgressBars:

```
<style name="MyCustomProgressBar" parent="android:Widget.ProgressBar.Small">
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/loader_background</item>
    <item name="android:indeterminateDrawable">@drawable/loader_indeterminate</item>
</style>
```

Background image is way bigger compared to the images of the animation, however, when I try the code above image and background appear of the same size, it's like the background is tied to the 'indeterminateDrawable' image size. Is possible to change the background size independently?

Answer (score 1):

Just FYI I found a workaround. Just use padding on the ProgressBar, just like this:

```
<style name="MyCustomProgressBar" parent="android:Widget.ProgressBar.Large">
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/loader_background</item>
    <item name="android:indeterminateDrawable">@drawable/anim_indeterminate</item>
    <item name="android:padding">35dp</item>
</style>
```

I hope it helps somebody!